# Компиляция .exe из скрипта python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcp-ip, pyinstaller

Всем доброго времени суток. Написал TCP/IP чат с графическим интерфейсом tkinter и сервер, попытался скомпилировать клиент через pyinstaller и запустить, но во время подключения к серверу программа вылетает с ошибкой. То есть, первоначальное окно запускается, а при подключении клиент умирает. В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В Ide всё работает, но в exe такие ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер:

```py
import socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import pypyodbc


def registration(client):
    connection = pypyodbc.connect(*Моя бд*)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    nickname = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    password = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")

    mySQLQuery = ("""
                                    INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Nickname, Password)
                                    VALUES('{}','{}')

                            """).format(nickname, password)
    cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
    cursor.commit()
    connection.close()


def authentication(client):
    connection = pypyodbc.connect(*Моя бд*)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    while True:
        nickname = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
        password = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")

        mySQLQuery = ("""
                           SELECT Nickname, Password
                           FROM dbo.Users
                           WHERE Nickname = '{}' AND Password = '{}'
                       """).format(nickname, password)

        cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(results) != 0:
            client.send(bytes("Accepted", "utf8"))
            connection.close()
            return nickname
        else:
            client.send(bytes("Declined", "utf8"))


def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        name = authentication(client)
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, name)).start()


def handle_client(client, name):  # Takes client socket and name as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    welcome = 'Welcome to the chat, %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name

    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)

        if msg == bytes("b233e775d63bb8b86cf031776d4caea613f59cda", "utf8"):
            registration(client)

        elif msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
            broadcast(msg, name + ": ")

        else:
            client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
            break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    """Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8") + msg)


clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print("Address: " + HOST)
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Server started!")
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

Клиент:

```py
import hashlib
import tkinter
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def receive(event=None):
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:
            break


def registration(event=None):
    def reg_button(event=None):
        nickname = nic_entry.get()
        password = pas_entry.get()
        hpas = hashlib.sha1(password.encode())
        htmp = hpas.hexdigest()
        client_socket.send(bytes(nickname, "utf8"))
        client_socket.send(bytes(htmp, "utf8"))
        nic_entry.destroy()
        pas_entry.destroy()
        reglabel1.destroy()
        reglabel2.destroy()

        def reg_return(event=None):
            knopka.destroy()
            lb.destroy()
            bt.destroy()
            entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
            entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
            send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
            send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
            entry_field.pack()
            send_button.pack()

        lb = tkinter.Label(top, text="User has been registered!", fg="green")
        bt = tkinter.Button(top, text="OK")
        bt.bind("<Button-1>", reg_return)

        lb.pack()
        bt.pack()

    client_socket.send(bytes("b233e775d63bb8b86cf031776d4caea613f59cda", "utf8"))

    registration_button.destroy()
    entry_field.destroy()
    send_button.destroy()

    Nickname.set("")
    Password.set("")

    nic_entry = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=Nickname)
    pas_entry = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=Password)
    reglabel1 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Nickname:")
    reglabel2 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Password:")
    knopka = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send")
    knopka.bind("<Button-1>", reg_button)

    knopka.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    nic_entry.pack()
    pas_entry.pack()
    reglabel1.pack()
    reglabel2.pack()


def authentication(event=None):
    nickname = entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    hpas = hashlib.sha1(password.encode())
    htmp = hpas.hexdigest()
    client_socket.send(bytes(nickname, "utf8"))
    client_socket.send(bytes(htmp, "utf8"))

    msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    if msg == "Accepted":
        global checkadm

        if nickname == "Admin":
            checkadm = True
        else:
            checkadm = False

        button.destroy()
        lb = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname and Password are correct!", fg="green")
        lb.grid(row=3, column=2)
        bt = tkinter.Button(au, text="OK")
        bt.bind("<Button-1>", au_destroy)
        bt.grid(row=2, column=1)

    else:
        lb = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname and Password are incorrect!", fg="red")
        lb.grid(row=3, column=2)


def au_destroy(event=None):
    au.destroy()


def send(event=None):
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()


def get_address(event=None):
    global HOST
    global PORT
    HOST = host.get()
    PORT = port.get()
    connect.destroy()


# Sockets
connect = tkinter.Tk()
connect.title("Chatter")
HOST, PORT = "", ""
host, port = tkinter.StringVar(), tkinter.StringVar()

label1 = tkinter.Label(connect, text="Host:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(connect, text="Port:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(connect, textvariable=host)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(connect, textvariable=port)
button = tkinter.Button(connect, text="Send")
button.bind("<Button-1>", get_address)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

connect.mainloop()

# Port management
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

# Authentication

au = tkinter.Tk()
au.title("Authentication")
Password, Nickname = tkinter.StringVar(), tkinter.StringVar()

label1 = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(au, text="Password:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(au, textvariable=Nickname)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(au, textvariable=Password)
button = tkinter.Button(au, text="Send")
button.bind("<Button-1>", authentication)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=35)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=35, sticky='nw')
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

au.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
au.mainloop()

# Chat
if checkadm:
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Chatter")

    my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
    my_msg.set("")

    messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
    msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=45, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
    entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
    send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
    send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
    registration_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Register")
    registration_button.bind("<Button-1>", registration)

    scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    messages_frame.pack()
    entry_field.pack()
    send_button.pack()
    registration_button.pack()

    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
else:
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Chatter")

    my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
    my_msg.set("")

    messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
    msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=45, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
    entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
    send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)

    scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    msg_list.pack()
    messages_frame.pack()
    entry_field.pack()
    send_button.pack()

    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте ловить исключение, добавив `try`/`except`, иначе любое исключение будет вызывать падение скрипта/программы.

Еще можно повесить обработчик неотловленных исключений через [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) добавив [метод вывода исключения](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f47c9a9357a7cb024c1a4b4710ce33308239f694/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/hook_exceptions_in_Qt.py#L11). Ошибку можно вывести через [tkinter.messagebox.showerror](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#tkinter.messagebox.showerror).

Пример:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print('Error: ', text)
    messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message=text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Полный пример для клиента:

```
import hashlib
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import traceback

import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print('Error: ', text)
    messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message=text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


def receive(event=None):
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:
            break


def registration(event=None):
    def reg_button(event=None):
        nickname = nic_entry.get()
        password = pas_entry.get()
        hpas = hashlib.sha1(password.encode())
        htmp = hpas.hexdigest()
        client_socket.send(bytes(nickname, "utf8"))
        client_socket.send(bytes(htmp, "utf8"))
        nic_entry.destroy()
        pas_entry.destroy()
        reglabel1.destroy()
        reglabel2.destroy()

        def reg_return(event=None):
            knopka.destroy()
            lb.destroy()
            bt.destroy()
            entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
            entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
            send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
            send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
            entry_field.pack()
            send_button.pack()

        lb = tkinter.Label(top, text="User has been registered!", fg="green")
        bt = tkinter.Button(top, text="OK")
        bt.bind("<Button-1>", reg_return)

        lb.pack()
        bt.pack()

    client_socket.send(bytes("b233e775d63bb8b86cf031776d4caea613f59cda", "utf8"))

    registration_button.destroy()
    entry_field.destroy()
    send_button.destroy()

    Nickname.set("")
    Password.set("")

    nic_entry = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=Nickname)
    pas_entry = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=Password)
    reglabel1 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Nickname:")
    reglabel2 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Password:")
    knopka = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send")
    knopka.bind("<Button-1>", reg_button)

    knopka.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    nic_entry.pack()
    pas_entry.pack()
    reglabel1.pack()
    reglabel2.pack()


def authentication(event=None):
    nickname = entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    hpas = hashlib.sha1(password.encode())
    htmp = hpas.hexdigest()
    client_socket.send(bytes(nickname, "utf8"))
    client_socket.send(bytes(htmp, "utf8"))

    msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    if msg == "Accepted":
        global checkadm

        if nickname == "Admin":
            checkadm = True
        else:
            checkadm = False

        button.destroy()
        lb = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname and Password are correct!", fg="green")
        lb.grid(row=3, column=2)
        bt = tkinter.Button(au, text="OK")
        bt.bind("<Button-1>", au_destroy)
        bt.grid(row=2, column=1)

    else:
        lb = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname and Password are incorrect!", fg="red")
        lb.grid(row=3, column=2)


def au_destroy(event=None):
    au.destroy()


def send(event=None):
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()


def get_address(event=None):
    global HOST
    global PORT
    HOST = host.get()
    PORT = port.get()
    connect.destroy()


# Sockets
connect = tkinter.Tk()
connect.title("Chatter")
HOST, PORT = "", ""
host, port = tkinter.StringVar(), tkinter.StringVar()

label1 = tkinter.Label(connect, text="Host:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(connect, text="Port:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(connect, textvariable=host)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(connect, textvariable=port)
button = tkinter.Button(connect, text="Send")
button.bind("<Button-1>", get_address)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

connect.mainloop()

# Port management
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

# Authentication

au = tkinter.Tk()
au.title("Authentication")
Password, Nickname = tkinter.StringVar(), tkinter.StringVar()

label1 = tkinter.Label(au, text="Nickname:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(au, text="Password:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(au, textvariable=Nickname)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(au, textvariable=Password)
button = tkinter.Button(au, text="Send")
button.bind("<Button-1>", authentication)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=35)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=35, sticky='nw')
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

au.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
au.mainloop()

# Chat
if checkadm:
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Chatter")

    my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
    my_msg.set("")

    messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
    msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=45, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
    entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
    send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
    send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
    registration_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Register")
    registration_button.bind("<Button-1>", registration)

    scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    messages_frame.pack()
    entry_field.pack()
    send_button.pack()
    registration_button.pack()

    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
else:
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Chatter")

    my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
    my_msg.set("")

    messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
    msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=45, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
    entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
    send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)

    scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    msg_list.pack()
    messages_frame.pack()
    entry_field.pack()
    send_button.pack()

    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
top.mainloop()
```